# read and write data from nested python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a somewhat big and nested dictionary. A user specifies a "mapping" in a text file where he tells me what values in the dictionary to copy.

example line: a/b/c/d -> A/B/C

So in Python I would make sure the target keys exist and then write

```
myDict["A"]["B"]["C"] = myDict["a"]["b"]["c"]["d"]
```

Is there a function to automate this and use a list of keys to access the specific part of the dictionary? Something like

```
source = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
target = ["A", "B", "C"]
myDict.whereToGo(target) = myDict.whereToGo(source)
```

Edit: Already answered, but to clarify for future readers. I want to concatenate an xml and a json file. After choosing a method to convert xml to json I ended up with information that is provided two times (once from the original json and once from the original xml), but only one of them is "correct". The user is given the option to specify a mapping from the xml to the json file (in my case a/b/c/d in xml file to A/B/C in json file, but there could be multiple lines in that text file).

Comment: I don't understand what you need to do. Do you want to append new key/values to your existing dictionary? Do you want to create a new dict from the existing key/values in the old dictionary where just the keys are changed? Do you want to create a new dictionary structure just from the old values with the mapping keys?

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you add an algorithm, an example or a detailed pseudo code ?

Comment: I agree... The question is not clear. Please elaborate what this mapping is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can build a function to retrieve the nested value:

```
def whereToGo(key_list, dict):
    if key_list:
        key = key_list.pop(0)
        value = whereToGo(key_list, dict[key])
        return value

    else:
        return dict
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not especially clear.  Taking your example literally, you could answer it like this:

```
# "Make the below happen"
# lookup["A"]["B"]["C"] = original["a"]["b"]["c"]["d"]
import collections

def infinite_dict():
    return collections.defaultdict(infinite_dict)

original = {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': 'value!'}}}}
lookup = infinite_dict()
lookup["A"]["B"]["C"] = original["a"]["b"]["c"]["d"]
assert lookup['a']['b']['c'] == 'value!'
```

If on the other hand you wanted to provide a magical object that did dynamic mapping from e.g.:

```
# for any given x, y, z
assert lookup[x][y][z] == original[z][y][x][42]
```

then this is possible as well, but more involved, and probably a bad idea.  Included as a cautionary tale, please rethink your approach:

[image: Please no]

```
import inspect

class RemappedDict(object):
     def __init__(self, lookup, needed=None, args=()):
         '''
         source is the base dict used to index into
         '''
         if needed is None:
             needed = len(inspect.getargspec(lookup).args)
         if needed < 1:
             raise ValueError('This is not going to go well')
         self.__lookup = lookup
         self.__needed = needed
         self.__args = args

     def __getitem__(self, item):
         new_args = self.__args + (item,)
         new_needed = self.__needed - 1
         if not new_needed:
             return self.__lookup(*new_args)
         return RemappedDict(self.__lookup, new_needed, new_args)
```

then you could use this like

```
original = {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': 'value!'}}}}
logic = lambda x, y, z: original[z][y][x]["d"]
lookup = RemappedDict(logic)
assert lookup['c']['b']['a'] == 'value!'
```